# How to use 'Remove Tags' in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

`*** Settings ***
Default Tags   vinoth    kumar

*** Testcase ***
First test-case       Remove Tags   vinoth
Second test-case   Log Variables   level=WARN


Here i got,
      @{TEST_TAGS} = [ vinoth | kumar ]
`
How to delete tags form this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code block, The tag vinoth gets removed from the "First test-case", but not from the "Second test-case" because you are removing the tag only in the "First test-case"

The reason is, default tags are applied test suite wide.

```
*** Settings ***
Default Tags      vinoth    kumar

*** Test Cases ***
First test-case
    Remove Tags     vinoth
    Log Many    @{TEST_TAGS}

Second test-case
    Log Many    @{TEST_TAGS}
```